# PHP counting months backward

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I am new here, is there month script that counting backward 24 months instead of 2 years?

```
    <?php
        $curYear = date(Y);
        $minYear = $curYear - 2;
     ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($) {
            $('#child_birthday').datepicker({
              changeMonth: true,
              changeYear: true,
              yearRange: '<?php echo $minYear; ?>:<?php echo $curYear; ?>'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi if i use 2 years, the calendar allows to pick a date that go back to the begining of the 2013. If i can use 24 months, then it wouldnt allow to go back before the september of 2013.

Answer (score 0):

To restrict the user from selecting a date that's before 9/2013, use the `minDate` option

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate

```
 <?php
    $curYear = date('Y');
    $minYear = $curYear - 2;
    $curMonth = date('j');
 ?>

    jQuery(function($) {
        $('#child_birthday').datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          minDate: new Date(<?php echo $minYear; ?>, <?php echo $curMonth ?> - 1, 1),
          yearRange: '<?php echo $minYear; ?>:<?php echo $curYear; ?>'
        });
    });
```

By the way, you can calculate the current year & month directly in javascript, so there's no need to calculate in php and pass the results to javascript.